# Hudson/Jenkins -- how to access a private git repository on BitBucket.com

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, hudson, bitbucket

This question is long and multifaceted, so I'll start with a
brief overview, and then show in detail everything I've tried and my
questions as to why they don't work and what I'm doing wrong.

### Overview

I'm trying to setup a Build Job on Hudson for source code on a private
repository on BitBucket. There are a lot of similar questions on Stack
Overflow, but for various reasons none of them address my needs.

I would like to access it using https instead of ssh, but there
seems no way forward accessing it in Hudson with https, and everyone
on the web seems sold on ssh. So I have tried to make it work with
ssh, but in vain.

So, my central question is:
 ***How can I access a private
BitBucket repository in Hudson?***

### Notes

- *I realize Jenkins is better, but I'm working with
  an established Hudson Server. Please, no advice about switching to
  Jenkins.
  I included Jenkins in the title and as a tag because more likely than not any solution will be applicable to both.*
- *Due to running into several dead-ends, I also ask a couple of "sub-questions" that elaborate on the core question above
  -- extra gratitude if you can enlighten me on them.*

### The Problem

I use the Git plugin for Hudson, and configure it as follows:

[image: Git Configuration]

Since this is a private repository, it needs authentication somehow.  So of course, the build failed.  Here are the relevant parts of the stack trace:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' 
hudson.plugins.git.GitException:
Could not clone https://TJamesBoone@bitbucket.org/OtherUser/projectname.git
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException:
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
https://TJamesBoone@bitbucket.org/OtherUser/projectname.git: not authorized
```

**Question:** *Why does the Git Plugin for Hudson not have a place in the project configuration for authentication for private repositories?  After all, the SVN plugin can deal with authentication.  Is there a good reason?*

### Things I Tried

I reconfigured the project to use the ssh url instead of the https url:

[image: Git Config with ssh url]

I then created a ssh key using **[this tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git#SetupSSHforGit-Step4.Createaconfigfile)** from Atlassian.  I then added the ssh key to the project on BitBucket.

I tried building again, and got this stack trace (relevant parts):

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' 
hudson.plugins.git.GitException:
Could not clone git@bitbucket.org:OtherUser/projectname.git
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException:
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
git@bitbucket.org:OtherUser/projectname.git:
UnknownHostKey: bitbucket.org. RSA key fingerprint is
97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
```

I then figured I should try to configure Hudson with the two ssh plugins that were available, the Publish Over SSH plugin and the SSH plugin (which I learned about **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515039/permission-denied-publickey-when-setting-up-jenkins/8143432#8143432)**).

But I can't figure out how to use them.  First, I assume I don't need the Publish Over SSH plugin, because I'm not trying to publish, I'm just trying to pull.  Secondly, the SSH plugin won't work for me.  I've tried doing this:

[image: SSH Sites Config]

But the problem here is that it can't connect.  Furthermore, it wants a port number, and if I enter in nothing, 22 is used as a default.  I have no idea what to do with it.

**Question:** *Do I even need to configure an SSH site in order to successfully put from this private BitBucket repository?*

### Summary

***How can I access a private
BitBucket repository in Hudson?***

In my Hudson build, I need to be able to pull from this private BitBucket repository.  I can't seem to make it work with ssh, and I don't even know if using https is possible as there's no place for me to put in a password.  If someone can help me either way, I'll be happy.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832596/unable-to-access-private-git-repositories-using-hudson?rq=1

Comment: No good, I don't have a ".ssh" folder as the answer to that question assumes.  The key is currently located in D:/Hudson/SSH.  Where am I supposed to get a .ssh folder?

Comment: You hould fine a .ssh folder in the profile of the Jenkins user.

Comment: This Hudson Server currently does not have authentication -- thus there are no users to work with.

Comment: I assume your hudson runs as a service. What account runs this service under?

Comment: Yes, it runs as a service -- I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "What account runs this service under?"  I figured the service is running on the machine, period.  Is it actually tied to a specific windows user?

Comment: If you didn't do anything special then it runs under the local system account. <del>You would need to add the .ssh folder to the system accounts profile. see http://serverfault.com/questions/112927/where-does-the-local-system-account-store-its-personal-files </del> You should actually create a dedicated user that the Jenkins service is running under and give that user permission (i.e. create the .ssh in that users profile)

Answer (score 2):

For HTTPS connection, you should define ALSO your password within the HTTPS query like :

```
https://TJamesBoone:**PASSWORD**@bitbucket.org/OtherUser/projectname.git
```

For SSH connection, as said, you should see that DOC : https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git
Don't forget to setup an EMPTY passphrase as jenkins does not support it.
Don't forget to login first with jenkins user to git using **ssh git@bitbucket.org**

I can't provide more info your SSH case as I'm not running it on windows.

If that is not working, please tell us if : 
* jenkins is runned as a service 
* if not, what is the webserver used to run jenkins